# Spring MVC Accessing Session Attribute in Function in Controller Class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session

I was having some problem when trying to access session attribute in Controller. I declared my session attributes as such:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ WebKeys.OBJECT_SIX, WebKeys.DSP_LOGIC, WebKeys.NEW_CARD_FORM })
```

In each of my API, I am calling the function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/apiA.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doAPIa(Model model) { 
    setInfo(model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/apiB.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doAPIb(Model model) { 
    setInfo(model);
}
```

In my setInfo(), I am trying to access the session attribute and add value back to the model:

```
private void setInfo(Model model) throws Exception{
    
    String populationId = // need to get from WebKeys.OBJECT_SIX session attribute
    if(populationId!=null && (populationId.equals(Constants.POP_TYPE_ID))){
        
        DisplayHelperTO helper = (DisplayHelperTO) // need to get from WebKeys.DSP_LOGIC;
        NewCardNewBasicForm newCardForm = (NewCardNewBasicForm ) // need to get from WebKeys.NEW_CARD_FORM);

        model.addAttribute("newCardForm", newCardForm);
        model.addAttribute("dspLogic", helper);
    }
}
```

I tried to declare in such way:

```
private void setInfo(Model model,
        @SessionAttribute(WebKeys.OBJECT_SIX) String populationId) throws Exception{
}
```

However, if I am declaring the function in this way, the part to call the setInfo() in both doAPIa and doAPIb will be highlighted in syntax error. Any ideas on how to access the session attributes in function? Thanks!

Comment: Anybody any ideas?